# How to Clip a PostGIS raster, and get a GeoTIFF out?

Tags: postgis, raster, clip

My end goal is to load the DEM of the entire country in the PostGIS Database, and create a service, which will take in a GeoJSON polygon, and give you a tiff file of that area.

For this, my Research is currently stuck in clipping the PostGIS raster table.

This is what I have done so far:

1. I loaded a small DEM tiff into the PostGIS database, using `raster2pgsql`. This has created a Table with 16 rows, and it can be successful seen as a Raster in QGIS.
2. I checked if the Given polygon intersects with the Table, using the following command:

`SELECT ST_Intersects(
    ST_SETSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 73.53, 18.57], [ 73.50, 18.45], [ 73.76, 18.48], [ 73.72, 18.58], [ 73.53, 18.57
     ] ] ] }'), 4326),
rast) from carto_dm1;`

This showed me that 2 rows of the table intersect with the given geometry, & 14 rows do not.

If I use ST_Clip, I get multiple records back. I'm using the following command:

`Select ST_Clip(rast, 
    ST_SETSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 73.53, 18.57], [ 73.50, 18.45], [ 73.76, 18.48], [ 73.72, 18.58], [ 73.53, 18.57] ] ] }'), 4326)
    ) from carto_dm1
    where 
ST_Intersects(
    ST_SETSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 73.53, 18.57], [ 73.50, 18.45], [ 73.76, 18.48], [ 73.72, 18.58], [ 73.53, 18.57] ] ] }'), 4326),
    rast);`

Now how do I get one clipped Raster out, which can be passed to  [ST_AsTIFF](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/RT_ST_AsTIFF.html), so that I can write a GeoTiff from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this, is to use the [ST_Union](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/RT_ST_Union.html) function. It combines all rasters into a single raster. This function is useful if your raster is tiled, or if you loaded several files into a table using `raster2pgsql`.

This can be the complete Query:

```
Select ST_AsTIFF(ST_UNION 
                (ST_Clip(rast, 
                        ST_SETSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 73.534496527777776, 18.573055555555555 ], [ 73.505329861111122, 18.452743055555555 ], [ 73.76782986111111, 18.480086805555555 ], [ 73.729548611111113, 18.585815972222221 ], [ 73.534496527777776, 18.573055555555555 ] ] ] }'), 4326))))
            from carto_dm1
            where 
            ST_Intersects(
                    ST_SETSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 73.534496527777776, 18.573055555555555 ], [ 73.505329861111122, 18.452743055555555 ], [ 73.76782986111111, 18.480086805555555 ], [ 73.729548611111113, 18.585815972222221 ], [ 73.534496527777776, 18.573055555555555 ] ] ] }'), 4326)
                ,rast);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have exported a GeoTiff from a clipped raster in Postgis with the following workflow and the use of large objects:

1.Creating a large object:

```
WITH buffer AS (
SELECT
    id,
    ST_Buffer(geom,50) AS geom
FROM polygon_table),

clip AS (
SELECT 
    partnumber,
    ST_Union(ST_Clip(a.rast, 1,b.geom, TRUE)) AS rast
FROM aspect a
    JOIN buffer b
    ON ST_Intersects(a.rast, b.geom)
        GROUP BY partnumber)

SELECT 
    oid, 
    lowrite(lo_open(oid, 131072), png) As num_bytes
    FROM (
    VALUES (lo_create(0),
           ST_AsGDALRaster(((SELECT ST_Union(rast) FROM clip)),'GTiff')
       )) As v(oid,png)
```

2.Exporting it to a GTiff file (e.g. with oid=176148)

```
SELECT lo_export(176148, '/tmp/demo_rast.tif')
```

(3. Deleting the large object: SELECT lo_unlink(176148))

The code is from a [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93163/raster-slightly-displaced-after-exporting-from-postgis-database) I have asked.

[Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83665/postgis-raster-outputting-raster-into-gdal-supported-file) are some more information.

Comment: Where do the ids: `131072` & `176148` come from?

Comment: This is a good approach. You can also do it with a pythonu function that saves the bytes directly.

Comment: The `131072` is a fix id to export raster files. The `176148` is the oid of the last query (see part 1). It is changing every time you call a query. This oid will shown in the result set of the last part of the query (see part 1)